# using isotope with fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope, fancybox-2

Excuse me for my english (I'm french), I hope to be clear in my explanations:
I want to use Fancybox2 with isotope, after much research I still can not make them work together.

When I filter a selection, fancybox does not take it into account and shows me all categories.

Here is my code:

```js
/* ==================================================
   Filter Works
================================================== */

BRUSHED.filter = function (){


        // filter items when filter link is clicked
        var $optionSets = $('#options .option-set'),
            $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

          $optionLinks.click(function(){

            var $this = $(this);
            // don't proceed if already selected
            if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
              return false;
            }
            var $optionSet = $this.parents('.option-set');
            $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selected');

            // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
            var options = {},
                key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
                value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
            // parse 'false' as false boolean
            value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
            options[ key ] = value;
            if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
              // changes in layout modes need extra logic
              changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
            } else {
              // otherwise, apply new options
              $containermasonry.isotope( options );
            }

            return false;
        });

}



/* ==================================================
   FancyBox
================================================== */

BRUSHED.fancyBox = function(){

        $(".fancybox").fancybox()   

// Make Fancybox Respect Isotope Filtering          HERE IS THE PROBLEME !?

$('#filters a').on("click", function(){
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-option-value'); 

  $('.masonry').isotope({ filter: selector }, function(){
    if(selector == "*"){
     $(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery");
    } else{ 
     $(selector).find(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", selector);
    }
  });
  return false;
}); 

}
```

```html
  <!-- Filter -->
                    <nav id="options" class="work-nav type-workmarge"> <!-- flotant +marge -->
                        <ul id="filters" class="option-set" data-option-key="filter">
                            <li class="type-work">Sélection</li>
                            <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All Projects</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".design">Design</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".photography">Photography</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#filter" data-option-value=".video">Video</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- End Filter -->

    <div id="worksss" class="masonry js-masonry" data-masonry-options='{ "isFitWidth": true }'>

    <!-- the list of my images -->
        <div class="item item-thumbs design"><a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The City" href="_include/img/work/image-01.jpg">
                                        <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                        <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>

                                    </a><img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-01.jpg" alt="Description">
        </div>
        <div class="item item-thumbs photography"><a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The City" href="_include/img/work/image-02.jpg">
                                        <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                        <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>

                                    </a><img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-02.jpg" alt="Description">
    <!-- etc-->
     </div>
```

If you have any advice or solutions, thank you very much in advance!!!

Comment: Check this if that helps https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fancybox/ncVsViD2v9o/JE0DHYPuEOgJ

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the link, I found nothing useful on it, however, I noticed that by removing the following line, it works!

```
$('.masonry').isotope({ filter: selector }, function(){
```

To summarize :

```
        $(".fancybox").fancybox()   

// Isotope Filtering 
$('#filters a').on("click", function(){
  var selector = $(this).attr('data-option-value'); 

  $('.masonry').isotope({ filter: selector }, function(){
    if(selector == "*"){
     $(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery");
    } else{ 
     $(selector).find(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", selector);
    }
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score -1):

insert either `filter: '.design'` or `filter: '.video'` -- your choice!!!

```
BRUSHED.filter = function () {
    if ($('#projects').length > 0) {
        var $container = $('#projects');

        $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $container.isotope({
                // options
                filter: '.design',
                animationEngine: 'best-available',
                itemSelector: '.item-thumbs',
                layoutMode: 'fitRows'
            });
        });
    }
};
```